# Rails: Using .references on joins even though it is not required

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I know that when you utilize `includes` and you specify a `where` clause on the joined table, you should use `.references`

example:

```
# will error out or throw deprecation warning in logs
customers = Customer.includes(:orders).where("Orders.cost < ?", 100)
```

Otherwise, in rails 4 or later, you will get an error like the following:

> Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'Orders.cost' in 'where clause': SELECT
>   `customers`.* FROM `customers` WHERE (Orders.cost < 100)

Or you will get a deprecation warning:

> DEPRECATION WARNING: It looks like you are eager loading table(s)
>    (one of: users, addresses) that are referenced in a string SQL
>    snippet. For example:
>
> ```
> Post.includes(:comments).where("comments.title = 'foo'")
> ```
>
> Currently, Active Record recognizes the table in the string, and knows
>    to JOIN the comments table to the query, rather than loading comments
>    in a separate query. However, doing this without writing a full-blown
>    SQL parser is inherently flawed. Since we don't want to write an SQL
>    parser, we are removing this functionality. From now on, you must explicitly
>    tell Active Record when you are referencing a table from a string:
>
> Post.includes(:comments).where("comments.title = 'foo'").references(:comments)
>
> If you don't rely on implicit join references you can disable the
>    feature entirely by setting `config.active_record.disable_implicit_join_references = true`. (
>
> SELECT "users"."id" AS t0_r0, "users"."name" AS t0_r1, "users"."email" AS t0_r2, "users"."created_at" AS t0_r3,
>   "users"."updated_at" AS t0_r4,
>           "addresses"."id" AS t1_r0, "addresses"."user_id" AS t1_r1, "addresses"."country" AS t1_r2, "addresses"."street" AS t1_r3,
>   "addresses"."postal_code" AS t1_r4, "addresses"."city" AS t1_r5,
>   "addresses"."created_at" AS t1_r6, "addresses"."updated_at" AS t1_r7
>    FROM "users" 
>    LEFT OUTER JOIN "addresses" ON "addresses"."user_id" = "users"."id" 
>    WHERE (addresses.country = 'Poland')

Makes sense.  Rails does not want to be an SQL parser when you utilize `includes`. So to make rails happy we do this:

```
# No error and no deprecation warning because we are explicitly specifying what table is referenced within that where clause
customers = Customer.includes(:orders).where("Orders.cost < ?", 100).references(:orders)
```

However, when you use `joins` and a `where` clause on the joined table: Rails does not error out, and rails also does not throw a deprecation warning as it does with `includes`:

```
# No error and no deprecation warning.  What????
customers = Customer.joins(:orders).where("Orders.cost < ?", 100)
```

This does not make sense to me.  I would think that if rails does not want to be an SQL parser for `includes`, then it also would not want to be an sql parser for `joins`. I would think that rails would prefer me to use `references` like so:

```
customers = Customer.joins(:orders).where("Orders.cost < ?", 100).references(:orders)
```

So my question(s):

1. Am I missing something?  Is it absolutely fine to not specify `references` for `joins` with `where` clauses on joined tables, even though it is pretty much required for `includes`?  If so: why this difference between `includes` and `joins`?
2. Should I specify `references` on `joins` moving forward?  Perhaps once rails' sql parser goes away all those `joins` with `where` clauses on joined tables will no longer work anymore?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The fundamental difference in between `joins` and `includes` (which is a wrapper for 2 methods : `eager_load` and `preload`) is that :

- `joins`bluntly executes SQL and returns all records indiscriminately
- `includes`will determine which records belongs to which model and build a tree of models : `author1 -> [post, post, post], author2 -> [post, post]`

For example if you join `Order.joins(:product_items)` you'll get :

- all ProductItem records intertwined with Orders.
- Whereas with `Order.includes(:product_items)` you'll *only* get `Orders` with product_items nested in each corresponding order.

So `reference` here is only useful to Rails when you do `includes` (or `eager_load` or `preload`) to help it differentiate the data coming out of a SQL join and assign it to the proper Models.

With `joins` you're on your own in SQL world. Most of the time I'll use it with `group("orders.id")` and an aggregate function :

`select(orders.*, count(product_items.id) as cart_size)`...

Comment: This helped me understand the difference between joins and includes which has bee confusing. thanks so much

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Unfortunately it has not sunk in for me yet.  Focusing on `eager_load` implementation of `includes`.  As I understand it:  `eager_load` bluntly executes SQL as well.  It does a left outer join on the records remaining in the temporary table, and then saves the tree of models. I guess what I am confused about is, from my understanding: both `joins` and `eager_load` create a temporary table and then then proceed to filter out records on that temporary table due to the `where` clause.  For some reason `joins` does not require `references` while `includes` does.

Comment: `joins` does an `inner join` and  `eager_loads `does an `outer left join`. But `joins` will return all the records from the SQL product of (customers * orders) intertwined, whereas `eager_load` and cie will process the raw records to dispatch customer data to `Customer`'s model and order data to `Order`'s data so you can then ask for `Customer.first.orders` in ruby.

Comment: I think my mistake was thinking that under the hood: `joins` creates a temporary table just like `eager_load` does, but that is not the case at all.  I thought `eager_load` creates a temp table b/c it is required for the left outer join.  Not so.  `includes` (whether that be `preload` or `eager_load`) creates a temporary table not for sql, but only because it has to in order to build the tree of models to load into memory.  The `.references` is there for the benefit of running the where clause on the temporary table, which is there for eager_loading purposes.  Not for sql. Sound right?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by tmp tables, but when you do a join in SQL it produces a new table with all combinations of the tables involved, filtered by the ON clause. AR only uses the raw result when called with `joins`. So if you Author.joins(:books) you get Tolstoi as many times as he wrote books. If you do Author.includes AR process the SQL result to redispatch the data to Author and Book so it's stays consistent (you get one Tolstoi and many Books)... Hope it make sense!

Comment: You don't need the call to references if you call eager_load - references is only there to help AR decide between eager_load and preload

Answer (score 1):

The key difference here is that `includes` has 2 modes of operation: eager_load (which uses a join for each association) and preload (which runs a separate query for each association and thus doesn't support conditions that reference the joined tables)

Before rails 2 (or thereabouts) the only option was the join based one. When the new strategy was introduced it was made the default, with a fallback to the old strategy if it looked like it was needed in order to reduce regressions in people's apps.

That detection was always a bit messy and there was a never ending long tail of cases that weren't detected, hence the eventual decision to remove the fallback and require the explicit use of `references` to indicate which included associations were used in any clauses of the query. You can see this in the [eager_loading?](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-2-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation.rb#L584) method that is used to decide which strategy to use.

You can also use `preload` or `eager_load` instead of `includes` to directly indicate which strategy you want (or to use different strategies for different associations).

On the other hand `joins` always does a join - it has never needed to parse your query because it simply doesn't need to - it will generate a join clause no matter what.